# Svelte: Specify multiple conditional class attributes

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css, svelte-3

I would like to have something like this made possible:

```
<div 
   class="overflow-scroll h-screen antialiased ..."
   class:whiteTheme="bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 ..."
   class:darkTheme="bg-blue-900 ..."
>
...
</div>
```

So one set of classes that will always be applied. One set only if `whiteTheme` is true and another only if `darkTheme` is true.

I know that i can define a `whiteTheme` and a `darkTheme` css class and make it just work like that

```
<div 
   class="overflow-scroll h-screen antialiased ..."
   class:whiteTheme
   class:darkTheme
>
```

But the point is that i want to design each element individual (esp. in the starting phase of my application). And having to define my set of classes for each element in a different class... defies for me the purpose in using Tailwind.css and experimenting on the specific elements (without jumping back and forth between css definitions and element definitions).

Another way i could choose is this:

```
<div 
   class="overflow-scroll h-screen antialiased ... {whiteTheme?'bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 ...':'bg-blue-900 ...'}">
```

This is kind of ok, but i would love to increase readability and maintainability by defining things in separate attributes...

So i'm wondering if there is a way to make it work the way i want to... E.g. can i extend the Svelte compiler for that easily ?

best
Johannes

Answer (score 24):

You are close with one of your proposals, but it does the opposite of what you want:
`class:something={condition}`

This will apply the *something* class when the *condition* is met.

So in your case you would have to do

```
class:bg-gray-100={whiteTheme}
class:text-gray-800={whiteTheme}
```

As an alternative you could do

```
<script>
 $: whiteThemeClasses = whiteTheme ? "gray text..." : "";
 ...
...class=" fixedclasses {whiteThemeClasses} {blackThemeClasses}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks i'am aware of these... But while if find the first approach not practical for me because if probably have more than one property the second approach is, because i have multiple elements with different classes and there is also the gab between definition and usage!

Answer (score 10):

You could place the classlist for light and dark into string variables and switch between those with a ternary based on the truthiness of the variable darkTheme in a store so it updates all components on change.

It allows for you to style each component individually for light and dark themes, increases readability quite a bit since a space separated string is similar to what we're used to seeing with css, and you can bring the class list up to the top of each component to maintain visibility/ease of access.

```html
<script>
    let light = 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 shadow-xl';
    let dark = 'bg-blue-900 text-white';
    
    import { darkTheme } from './store.js';
</script>

<div class="overflow-scroll h-screen p-3 {$darkTheme? dark : light}" >
...
</div>
```

EDIT:

**This only applies to Tailwind users, not if you're still trying to conditionally apply multiple classes.

Tailwind 2 now takes care of this for us with [dark classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode).

First you need to switch on [manual toggling](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually) of dark mode in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

Then You can conditionally apply the dark class to a single top level container and all components nested inside can use the dark:class-name and it will apply the dark theme. No need to pass state or import your store with dark variable into every component.

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/400e9aa749554b79971ad5442e8957fd?version=3.18.1) using a fixed stylesheet since Tailwind 2 CDN does not ship `darkMode` as class.

Comment: If you'd like to keep your styling variables within your HTML template, you can set the variable using the @const tag:

`{@const themeClasses = $darkTheme? "bg-blue-900 text-white" : "bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 shadow-xl"}`
In my opinion it helps with readability as it will be right next to its reference.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after some more digging i decided to go with the following patterns:

- Use the Tailwind plugin https://github.com/ChanceArthur/tailwindcss-dark-mode. This kind of solution keeps things on the tailwind level (in that perspective it's good). Code looks like

```
<div 
   class="overflow-scroll 
          h-screen 
          antialiased 
          ... 
          bg-gray-100 
          text-gray-800
          ...
          dark:bg-blue-900
          dark:text-yellow-200
          ..."
>
...
</div>
```

- This is pretty good for all "static" styling. With dynamic things like an `active/selected` element, i settled with using styles:

```
import { darkTheme } from '../stores.js';
...
<div
    class:selected
    class:$darkTheme
...
<style>
.selected {
    // all common styles
    @apply cursor-default;

    // all light styles
    @apply text-blue-600;
    @apply border-blue-600;
}

.selected.\$darkTheme {
    // all dark styles
    @apply text-yellow-700;
    @apply border-yellow-700;
}
</style>
```

I figured for smaller components using the styles is not to bad. However i still would find the possibility of defining custom task in Svelte intriguing... or a changed syntax like `class:true/false={my classes ...}`

Some additional notes:

- Similar to the plugin https://github.com/ChanceArthur/tailwindcss-dark-mode I found a nice blog post which yields kind of the same results by just using a custom `screen` definition: https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/support-mojave-dark-mode-with-tailwind-css/.

  - However this solely relies on a media query, so if you wanna have a custom light/dark switch in your app... i found no way for it.
  - The benefit using this approach however is that you can use `@apply` in combination with it, which you cannot using the plugin... currently (https://github.com/ChanceArthur/tailwindcss-dark-mode/issues/3).

Comment: This is actually quite an elegant solution, considering the constraints of both Tailwind and Svelte. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<h1 class="text-black dark:text-white">Hello world!</h1>
```

Just follow this tutorial [here](https://dev.to/smartmointy/tailwind-css-dark-mode-switch-with-javascript-2kl9)!

Answer (score -1):

Do this like that:

```
className={`block text-sm font-medium leading-5 ${
            dark ? 'text-gray-800' : 'text-gray-300'
          }`}
```

This is just an example of conditional class formatting, you can modify it with your condition and property style variables

Comment: this is totally wrong, when you want to render things conditionally then we need to replace the full string:

```
className={`${dark ? 'text-gray-800 block text-sm font-medium leading-5 ' : 'text-gray-300 block text-sm font-medium leading-5 '}`}
```